# Border Radius Preview Tool

Tags: javascript, performance, beginner, css, ecmascript-6

I am running through an app idea to help improve my knowledge of Javascript. The code attached performs the following:

- Performs a regex on the input field to check it is value 0-9 If not,
- it clears the field and shows a warning (Although this only seems to work on FF)
- If it passes, updates the styles of the preview box on keyup
- Adds the styles to a text area that the user can copy when selecting the
  button

I am looking for suggestions where I can improve in terms of writing more efficient code. Or pointers where I have possibly used the wrong method to perform a task. One area where I struggled was getting the value of the input field.

This is the first stage for this application as in the near future I plan to add in the ability modify each corner.

Feedback is welcomed

```js
"use strict"

const masterField = document.getElementById('masterField');
const box = document.getElementById('box');
const warn = document.getElementById('warn');
const styleSheet = document.getElementById('styleSheet');

const WARNING_TIME = 2000;
var warningTimer;

masterField.addEventListener('keyup', updateCss);

function updateCss() {
    let inputVal = this.value;
    console.log(this.value);
    const expCase = /[0-9]/;

    if (expCase.test(inputVal)) {
        box.style.borderRadius = inputVal + 'px';
        styleSheet.textContent = 'border-radius: ' + inputVal + 'px';
    } else {
        this.value = '';
        showWarning();
    }
}

function hidewarning() {
    warn.classList.add('hide-warning');
}

function showWarning() {
    clearTimeout(warningTimer);
    warningTimer = setTimeout(hidewarning, WARNING_TIME);
    warn.classList.remove('hide-warning');
}

function copyStyles() {
    styleSheet.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
}
```

```css
#box {
            width: 300px;
            height: 175px;
            background-color: red;
        }

        #warn {
            display: block;
        }

        #warn.hide-warning {
            display: none;
        }
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
    <div>
        <label for="masterField">All Corners</label>
        <input id="masterField" class="radius-field" type="number">
        <span id="warn" class="hide-warning">Only numbers 0 - 9 are allowed</span>
    </div>

    <button onclick="copyStyles()">Copy Styles</button>

    <textarea id="styleSheet"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## UI

Instead of a number input, a [range input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range) could be used - with the minimum value being zero and the maximum value being half of the lesser of the height and width - in this case 88 pixels (i.e. 175px / 2). With such an input there is no need to validate user input to ensure non-numeric characters are entered.

With the current interface, the event handler that fires when a key is pressed does not execute when the value changes from other means (e.g. mouse click). To be thorough, it might be better to observe the `change` event on the input as well.

## Code

The JavaScript code makes good use of `const` for values that don't get re-assigned, and uses `getElementById()` (as I mentioned in [a review of your *Nav scroll* code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/205457/120114)). I like how the constant for the warning time is in all capitals, and all lines are terminated with a semi-colon.

The regular expression could be simplified slightly to use the shorthand character class `\d` instead of `[0-9]`.